# Cannot access inner class in bean

Tags: jsf-2, el, inner-classes, managed-bean

I'm using JSF 2.0. I have a managed bean which I can access through my xhtml page. Inside the bean I declared an inner class. I can access `ArrayList<String>` of managed bean but not `ArrayList<InnerClass>` and I get the error that the InnerClass does not have a readable property. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That can happen if the inner class is not `public`. It will then be invisible to other classes outside the package (like as JSF/EL itself!). Make sure that the inner class is `public` whenever you need to access it by JSF/EL.

```
public class Bean {

    public class InnerClass {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Otherwise it will be interpreted as `String` and you'll get confusing exceptions like

> javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml: Property 'someProperty' not readable on type java.lang.String

when you want to access `#{innerClass.someProperty}`.

Comment: I found this after 2 hours of looking for a bug. I guess they should at least make the exception more clear. The String here refers to the expected type(in my case it was boolean), which is really confusing.